# left join on same table - taking too long

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query is taking 6-7 hours, is there any way i can enhance the performance.

```
SELECT  
    SUM(INV1.cur_book_bal),
    SUM(inv2.cur_book_bal),
    SUM(INV3.CUR_BOOK_BAL),
    SUM(INV4.CUR_BOOK_BAL)  
FROM
    table1 inv1 
LEFT JOIN
    table1 inv2 ON inv1.CIF_KEY = inv2.CIF_KEY
LEFT JOIN
    table1 inv3 ON inv1.CIF_KEY = inv3.CIF_KEY
LEFT JOIN
    table1 inv4 ON inv1.CIF_KEY = inv4.cif_key
                AND inv1.date = '30-JUN-2014' 
                AND inv2.date = '30-juN-2015' 
                AND INV3.dATE = '30-JUNE-2016' 
                AND INV4.DATE = '30-JUNE-17'
```

Comment: Are you using mysql OR sql-server? And what is your table structure?

Comment: Where are your indexes? What volume of data are we talking?

Comment: prob 2-3million rows in the table.. index is on date

Comment: using sql on an oracle databse

Comment: _Oracle_?  Then why did you tag your question with every other database?

Comment: it is sql server sorry

Comment: Can you tell us what is the logic behind your query?  Maybe it can be simplified to avoid the joins.  Add an index on `CIF_KEY`.

Comment: im trying to run analysis on customer a over 4 date periods i the same table, checking what their account balance is at each point in time

Comment: I suspect you want to apply those specific date filters not as part of an outer join but instead as part of a `WHERE` clause. E.g., for your last join I suspect you'd rather want: `left  join table1 inv4
on inv1.CIF_KEY= inv4.cif_key
WHERE inv1.date = '30-JUN-2014' and inv2.date = '30-juN-2015' AND INV3.dATE = '30-JUNE-2016' AND INV4.DATE = '30-JUNE-17'`

Comment: i was told to remove the where clause as it was dropping records where no match was found in the join

Comment: Are we getting the full picture here?  You are joining the tables on CIF_KEY but your Sum is everything.  Should we be seeing a GROUP BY with a WHERE or HAVING?  As an aside, in my experience it would be far quicker to do four separate sums with specific WHERE clause than try to combine all into one as you are attempting.

Comment: sure ive left out cif_key in a select and join.. picture is still the same though

Comment: @bbb Please show us what you are trying to do here.  Most likely a series of conditional aggregations could do what you want in much faster time.

Comment: SELECT  inv1.cif_key, SUM(INV1.cur_book_bal),SUM(inv2.cur_book_bal),SUM(INV3.CUR_BOOK_BAL),SUM(INV4.CUR_BOOK_BAL)  
from table1 inv1 
left  join table1 inv2
on inv1.CIF_KEY= inv2.CIF_KEY
left join table1 inv3
on inv1.CIF_KEY= inv3.CIF_KEY
left  join table1 inv4
on inv1.CIF_KEY= inv4.cif_key
and inv1.date = '30-JUN-2014' and inv2.date = '30-juN-2015' AND INV3.dATE = '30-JUNE-2016' AND INV4.DATE = '30-JUNE-17' group by inv1.cif_key

Comment: @bbb OK, but you'll still want to move your various JOIN conditions around because as it is, all of those conditions only apply to that final join, which likely is part of the reason your query takes so long. E.g., `left  join table1 inv2
on inv1.CIF_KEY= inv2.CIF_KEY and inv2.date = '30-juN-2015'` etc.

Comment: I don't see the point of these self joins.  Please show sample input and output.

Comment: thanks nb1987 will try now..

Comment: Tim, sample output will be cif_key 11111, bal1 $20, bal2 $25, bal3 $19, bal4 $60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to filter the data before making your join  like below:

```
with TABLE_DATA as    
(    
select  CIF_KEY ,date, sum(cur_book_bal)cur_book_bal from table1  where Date in ('30-JUN-2014','30-juN-2015','30-JUNE-2016','30-JUNE-17')    
group by CIF_KEY,date    
)    
SELECT  INV1.cur_book_bal ,inv2.cur_book_bal,INV3.CUR_BOOK_BAL,INV4.CUR_BOOK_BAL      
from TABLE_DATA inv1     
left  join TABLE_DATA inv2    
on inv1.CIF_KEY= inv2.CIF_KEY    
left join TABLE_DATA inv3    
on inv1.CIF_KEY= inv3.CIF_KEY    
left  join TABLE_DATA inv4    
on inv1.CIF_KEY= inv4.cif_key    

where inv1.date = '30-JUN-2014' and inv2.date = '30-juN-2015' AND INV3.dATE = '30-JUNE-2016' AND INV4.DATE = '30-JUNE-17'
```

Comment: not sure if this works, as the sample data must be 2014 i.e that is the starting sample. sorry that information should have been given.. i.ie sample 2014, then left join to all other dates

Answer (score 0):

The best way to write this query uses conditional aggregation.  I'm pretty sure this gets the result that you want:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2014-06-30' THEN curr_book_bal else 0 end),
       SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2015-06-30' THEN curr_book_bal else 0 end),
       SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2016-06-30' THEN curr_book_bal else 0 end),
       SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2017-06-30' THEN curr_book_bal else 0 end),
FROM table1 inv1 
WHERE date in ('2014-06-30', '2015-06-30', '2016-06-30', '2017-06-30');
```

With an index on `table1(date, curr_book_bal)`, this should be both blazingly fast and accurate.

Note the use of a standard date format.  This is highly recommended when writing date constants in a query.

Comment: so i don't need any joins then for the cif_key?

Comment: im finding the joins in the above suggested query gives me too much volume.. i.e the benchmark volume should be the 2014 date and when i join it gives me too much volume

Comment: @bbb . . . Your comment seems to suggest that the join version is producing incorrect results.  Are you saying this does not produce the right values?